# Magic/fae book series about a girl who finds a stone/rock and comes to some realization about its magic

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

There were at least 3 books. I believe told from different perspectives. There was a scene where someone is attending a girls boarding school, and the headmistress has one of the magic stones in her necklace.

The first book had a female face on the cover, with a blue tint over everything. The second book I believe was the same style but green.

I believe it was medieval or Victorian. Similar to our world but with magic. The stones were little known about. I think they used glamour spells, & possibly shape-shifting. I believe one of the main characters could somehow see that characters had a glamour on?

I read these around 2005-2010.

Comment: Is the boarding school set in the modern era? Victorian? Medieval? Is it recognizably set in our world? An alternate history? Another world entirely? Were the characters white? Black? Asian? Alien? Poor backgrounds on scholarship? Upper-class twits? Are the magic stones a central artifact in the series that everyone knows about? Only known about by historians? Common magic that everyone has access to?

Comment: How does the magic work? Is it divination? Summoning destructive lightning from the sky? Ritual magic? Learning the language of the universe and speaking True Names? Chi-based cultivation? Finding magical items in the world and attuning oneself to them? Pleasing legal cases for how the invocation should function?

Comment: I believe it was medieval or victorian. Similar to our world but with magic. The stones were little known about. I think they used glamour spells, & possibly shape-shifting. I believe one of the main characters could somehow see that characters had a glamour on?

Comment: Thank you so much for the questions, definitely had me digging deep. I wish I could remember more!

Answer (score 3):

Slightly challenging your question framing, might it have been a gem in a ring as per E. Rose Sabin's *[A School for Sorcery](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/798518)*?

> A second long-fingered hand moved into the light, this one wearing a ring with a large orange gem that sent reflected sparkles dancing over the papers and books piled on the desk. “I always acquaint myself with my students immediately upon their arrival,” the Headmistress said. Together the two hands plucked apart a stack of papers and drew out a single sheet. Tria recognized her application form. “I personally craft the course of study suited to each individual's needs and talents. Your instruction begins the moment I sign you in.”

Tria learns that she has magic, and is admitted to the Leslie Simonton School for the Magically Gifted, which is... very run down, the teachers barely seem to instruct them, and Tria constantly gets in trouble for using her magical gift accidentally, even though the teachers won't instruct her on how to use it.

The first book's cover is indeed blue, albeit more than just Tria's face, with the second book being more of a greenish color, and following a second character.

[image: Front cover of A School for Sorcery]

[image: Front cover of A Perilous Power]

These books are apparently part of a loose 9 book series, the *[Arucardi](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B085TL5SZF)* series.

Comment: Not this one, but thank you!